# handle zooming in lightweight chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

i want when my chart is created, chart automaticly zoom to 20 or 10 last candles.
[image]

its default zoom when chart creating.

[image]

this picture describes what i want.

is there a solution for this question?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that in several different ways:

- you can specify different [default bar spacing value](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions#barspacing)
- you can use [`setVisibleLogicalRange`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#setvisiblelogicalrange) method to change visible range
- you can use [`setVisibleRange`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#setvisiblerange) method to change visible range

Comment: Any advice on fixed price scale please. i mean i want to make the price scale at interval of 50 or 100 or any number as per need. No doubt i would stop mouse-click-drag for sclae manipulation using 'handleScale'.